# Array type doesn't support jQuery function Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, intellij-idea

I have below to code to display an array (result and arrays) using jQuery in IntelliJ.

```
for (var y = 0; y < result[0].length; y++) {
                    result[0][y].show();

for (var z = 0; z < arrays[0].length; z++){
                    arrays[0][z].show();
```

Interestingly the 'result' thrown an exception like below

> Uncaught TypeError: result[0][y].show is not a function

But it display fine for 'arrays'. When I checked both array object type by

```
typeof(result);
typeof(arrays);
```

All i get was 'object'. Below are screenshot of structure of array of both result and arrays.

result
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOZB6.png)

arrays
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4HS21.png)

So both are similar. Then why can't I use .show() for 'result' and thrown an error. If it's not appropriate type for jQuery .show(), please explain how I can find out that and let me know if there is any way to convert that array to able to support jQuery .show() function usage.
Please help.

Comment: Because it isn't a jQuery object.

Comment: *typeof* is an operator, not a function so `typeof result;`. ;-) And it is far better to post text than images.

Comment: Looks like your arrays are nested one level deeper than your code expects. `result[0][0]` is an array of 8 jQuery objects, not a jQuery object itself.

Comment: @MattMokary But jQuery function works on 'arrays' which have similar structure as 'result'

Comment: @RobG Noted. Will post in text next time. :)

Comment: @Venos Actually a jQuery object is not a JavaScript Array. They're similar: jQuery Object can hold a collection of DOM Elements, has a .length property, but it's not an Array.

Comment: @mrlew How can I know if it's a jQuery array or not? If its not, is it possible to convert it into jQuery array?

Comment: jQuery Object is not a "jQuery Array". From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jQuery): *The jQuery object itself behaves much like an array; it has a length property and the elements in the object can be accessed by their numeric indices [0] to [length-1]. Note that a jQuery object is not actually a Javascript Array object*

Comment: @Venos your objects are attached to the DOM? or were created on the fly? btw, you should iterate your array and show (if they are in the dom) or append somewhere (if not attached) your elements individually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

result[0][y] is not a jquery object, it's is an array.
You need to loop deeper.

Even the item inside array is DOM object not a jQuery object. You can convert it into jQuery object by using $()

Try this

```
for (var y = 0; y < result[0].length; y++) {
   for (var z = 0; z < result[0][y].length; z++) {
                $(result[0][y][z]).show();

for (var w = 0; w < arrays[0].length; w++){
   for (var x = 0; x < result[0][w].length; x++) {
                $(result[0][w][x]).show();
```